# How to display list data from database to spinner based on id properly?

Tags: java, android

i'm newbie in android studio. I'm trying to display list of NAMA_PROSES based on NOMOR_KK.
this is my database example

| NOMOR_KK | URUT | NAMA_PROSES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6666 | 1 | STICKER |
| 6666 | 2 | STAMPING, SISIR |
| 6666 | 3 | CETAK, PONZ, KELUPAS |
| 6666 | 4 | SORTIR IN ROLL |
| 6666 | 5 | RAJANG + COUNTER |
| 6037 | 1 | COATING & TREAT |
| 6037 | 2 | CETAK HOLOGRAM |
| 6037 | 3 | POTONG & SORTIR |
| 6037 | 4 | REWIND & SORTIR |

When i try to display NAMA_PROSES based on NOMOR_KK, the output is correct like the picture below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTAwh.png)

but when I change to another KK number, the history of the old KK number is still listed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbIfg.png)

i still looking for how to clear previous history

spinJSON.java

```
private void spinJSON(String response){
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
        if (obj.optString("kode").equals("true")){
            dataModels = new ArrayList<>();
            JSONArray dataArray = obj.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
                DataModel dataModel = new DataModel();
                JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

                dataModel.setNAMA_PROSES(dataobj.getString("NAMA_PROSES"));
                dataModels.add(dataModel);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dataModels.size(); i++){
                    getnamaProses.add(dataModels.get(i).getNAMA_PROSES().toString());
            }
                ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getnamaProses);
                spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinnerKK.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
            }
    } catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the logic of your code has nothing wrong, but you have to pay attention to this line:

```java
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getnamaProses);
```

The String targets to be chosen in the `Spinner` are from this variable `getnamaProses`.

Seems that `getnamaProses` is a global variable as I cannot see you declare it within the provided function. And you just keep adding String to `getnamaProses` without clearing it.

So you have to do something like `getnamaProses.clear();` before you add String to it.

Comment: thanks bro, i just focus with dataArray, until i read your comment after that my problem solved. you're the best